# Working code fails when imported into project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have a Scroll View tutorial that I customized to download images, rather than using local.

The project works fine.  When I import the two files and two corresponding View Controllers into my main project it crashes.  I'm getting the error

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I've set break points throughout the project, also set exception breakpoint, but can't locate the issue.  The Scroll View presents the first image then bombs.

First VC:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

class TutorialViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    var pages = [TutorialStepViewController]()
    var stringURLS: [String] = []
    var networkStatus = NetworkStatus.searching
    var constraintString = ""

    enum NetworkStatus {
        case searching
        case finishedSearching
    }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    getBrewerHistory(portalID: "7", galleryName: "Brewer History")

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func configureScrollView() {
        for i in 0..<stringURLS.count {
            let page = createAndAddTutorialStep(stringURLS[i], iconImageName: "", text: "")
            pages.append(page)
        }

        pageControl.numberOfPages = pages.count

        var views: [String: UIView] = ["view": view]

        for i in 0..<pages.count {
            views.updateValue(pages[i].view, forKey: "page" + String(i))
        }

    let metrics = ["edgeMargin": 10, "betweenMargin": 20]

    let verticalConstraints =
      NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|[page0(==view)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalConstraints)

    for page in 0..<pages.count {
        switch page {
        case 0:
            constraintString += "H:|-edgeMargin-[page" + String(page) + "(==view)]-betweenMargin-"
        case pages.count-1:
            constraintString += "[page" + String(page) + "(==view)]-edgeMargin-|"
        default:
            constraintString += "[page" + String(page) + "(==view)]-betweenMargin-"
        }
    }
    let horizontalConstraints =
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: constraintString, options: [.alignAllTop, .alignAllBottom], metrics: metrics, views: views)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(horizontalConstraints)

  }

  fileprivate func createAndAddTutorialStep(_ stringURL: String, iconImageName: String, text: String) -> TutorialStepViewController {
    let tutorialStep = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialStepViewController") as! TutorialStepViewController
    tutorialStep.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let stringURL = stringURL
    // tutorialStep.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: backgroundImageName)
    let imageURL = URL(string: stringURL)
    tutorialStep.backgroundImageURL = imageURL


    tutorialStep.iconImage = UIImage(named: iconImageName)
    tutorialStep.text = text

    scrollView.addSubview(tutorialStep.view)

    addChildViewController(tutorialStep)
    tutorialStep.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    return tutorialStep
  }
}

extension TutorialViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageWidth = scrollView.bounds.width
    let pageFraction = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(round(pageFraction))
  }
}

//Mark: Networking Calls
extension TutorialViewController {

    func getBrewerHistory (portalID: String, galleryName: String) {
        networkStatus = .searching
        activityIndicator.isHidden = false
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        let apiURL = "http://www.smarttapp.com/DesktopModules/DnnSharp/DnnApiEndpoint/Api.ashx?method=GetBrewerHistory"
        let params = ["PortalID" : portalID,
                      "GalleryName" : galleryName
        ]

        Alamofire.request(
            apiURL,
            method: .get,
            parameters: params
            )

            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                    print("Error while fetching JSON: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                    return
                }

                guard let responseArray = response.result.value as? [NSDictionary] else { return }

                for dict in responseArray {
                    if let url = dict["fileName"] as? String {
                        let fullURL = "http://www.smarttapp.com" + url
                        self.stringURLS.append(fullURL)
                    }
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                    self.networkStatus = .finishedSearching
                    self.configureScrollView()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Second VC:

```
import UIKit

class TutorialStepViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var iconImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var textLabel: UILabel!

  var backgroundImage: UIImage?
    var backgroundImageURL: URL?
  var iconImage: UIImage?
  var text: String?

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    backgroundImageView.af_setImage(withURL: backgroundImageURL!)

    iconImageView.image = iconImage

    if let text = text {
      let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size:20.0)!
      let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
      paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 8
      paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

      textLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle])
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you set the correct identifier for TutorialStepViewController ??
 let tutorialStep = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialStepViewController") as! TutorialStepViewController

Comment: Yes I did.  The scroll view is presenting the first downloaded image, so it's definitely picking it up.

Comment: The error happens in 1 line of code. Why are there over 100 lines of code in the question?!?!

Comment: Because I don't know what line of code the error occurs on.  As I said, I set breakpoints.  The code seems to fully execute and then bombs when the scrollview presents the first image.